# How to convert byte array to a string

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript

I have byte array. I want this array to be converted to a string.

Example:

```
Array = 124,123,123,123
String = "124123123123"
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This prints `"124123123123"`

```
dim a: a = array(124,123,123,123)
dim s: s = join(a, "")
wscript.echo(s)
```

However if the values are *bytes* then interpreting them as a character gives `"|{{{"`

```
dim i, z
for i = 0 to ubound(a)
    z = z & chr(a(i))
next
wscript.echo(z)
```